# .on and .off working together in multiple events and elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few editing options for a user to use, for example changing font-size or font-family or even color of a div, however I have a problem which hopefully is very simple for you guys.

Basically as soon as someone finish setting font-family or any other feature I would like to do .off event to stop specific feature from working.

Here's what is happening, someone chooses a font-family and change font in div1, then they choose font-size and want to change size of font in div2, however both font-family and font-size are applied because value from font-family is stored all the time.

I've got 3 solutions in mind but I am not sure if they are correct:
1. Do a loop that will do .off on every element expect one that is clicked.
2. Set only 1 variable that will be replaced by different value depending on which button is pressed?
3. Maybe use different event listener so each feature will work independently?

[Demonstration](https://youtu.be/7S9UnK4Cex8)

Here is little demonstration to show what I mean:
1. blue background color applied to div.
2. Choose font-family and apply to different div however background color is also applied.

When I choose font-family it should delete value of background color and don't apply it, only the font-family, vice versa

So to summarize I am looking for a solution on how to turn off event after it has been used and if button is pressed again, bind element back on so it works. To make sure each "event" listener is working independently and not together. I am not sure if I should put this in some loop or is there any other solution to this?

```
  var font;
    $("#fonts1").on("change", function(e){
        font = $(this).val();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#content-link2").on("click", "*", function(e) {
        $(this).css('font-family',font);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    var font2;
    $("#googlefonts1").on("change", function(){
        font2 = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#content-link2").on("click", "*", function() {
        $(this).css('font-family',font2);
    });
    var fsize;
    $("#fontsizes1").on("change", function(){
        fsize = $(this).val();
    });

<button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-primary" id="showColor">Show Colors</button>

            <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-primary" id="hideColor">Hide Colors</button>

            <input style="display: none" class="btn btn-default form-control margin" type="color" id="colorChoice">

            <a style="display: none" href="#" class="btn btn-default form-control margin" id="cp4">Background</a>

            <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#fonts1').bfhfonts({font: 'Arial'})" id="fontsShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Load Fonts</button>

            <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin" id="fontsHide">Hide Fonts</button>

            <select style="display: none" data-font="Arial" id="fonts1" class="form-control margin"></select>

            <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#googlefonts1').bfhgooglefonts({font: 'Lato'})" id="googleShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Google fonts</button>
            <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin" id="googleHide">Hide Google</button>
            <select style="display: none" id="googlefonts1" class="form-control margin"></select>
            <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#fontsizes1').bfhfontsizes({fontsize: '12'})" id="sizeShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Load font size</button>
            <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin" id="sizeHide">Hide font size</button>
            <select style="display: none" id="fontsizes1" class="form-control margin"></select>
            <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-default" id="finishEdit">Done</button>
            <button class="form-control margin btn btn-default" id="startEdit">Edit</button>
```

Comment: anyone know how to solve this issue?